# Template generating unwanted links

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am facing a very strange problem.When I open a web-page which is generated by Django using below template, I get an extra line which is not part of the template that I am using.
I have tried opening the page in IE,Firefox and Chrome, and getting the extra line everywhere.

**My Template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_SERVER_URL }}/static/env_rooms/chat.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_SERVER_URL }}/static/env_rooms/chat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://indlin232:9000/static/env_rooms/chat.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://indlin232:9000/static/env_rooms/chat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://apilinkidoobiz-a.akamaihd.net/gsrs?is=vtp1roin&bp=PB&g=6867cfa5-8f89-4c5a-ba03-53456e27686c" ></script></head>
  <body>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Any idea from where is this coming ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://apilinkidoobiz-a.akamaihd.net/gsrs?is=vtp1roin&bp=PB&g=6867cfa5-8f89-4c5a-ba03-53456e27686c" ></script>
```

Django Version :- 1.6.2
Python Version :- 2.7.5

Comment: http://malwaretips.com/blogs/linkidoo-virus-removal/ ... you have a virus ... its nothing to do with your template

Answer (score 0):

Script tags are frequently added by various javascript entities (browser extensions, other scripts on the page, viruses, etc.). I can't look up what that particular script is associated with because of my office's firewall, but I would suspect that one of those two things. Joran Beasley seems to have found that it's a virus on your machine.

Comment: Yeah ,it was linkdoo.I un-isntalled it. Everything is fine now.Thanks for answering.